# ¿Cómo mostrar el total de una consulta dentro de otra en MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Tengo 2 Tablas  `Albunes` e `Imagenes` con la siguiente extructura:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Albunes (
    Id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Nombre VARCHAR(100),
    Descripcion TEXT NULL,
    Fecha DATE NULL,
    Publicar TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 1,
    Propio TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 1,
    Created TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    Updated TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    Activo TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 1,
    PRIMARY KEY (Id)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Imagenes (
    Id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    fk_Id_Albunes INT UNSIGNED NULL,
    Codigo VARCHAR(150) NULL,
    Path VARCHAR(255) NULL,
    Created TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    Updated TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    Activo TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 1,
    PRIMARY KEY (Id),
    INDEX idx_Id_Albunes (fk_Id_Albunes ASC),
    CONSTRAINT `fk_Imagenes_Albunes`
        FOREIGN KEY (`fk_Id_Albunes`)
        REFERENCES `Albunes`(`Id`)
        ON DELETE SET NULL
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Quiero hacer una consulta que me devuelva la cantidad de imagenes de cada albun,
para un albun en particular sabiendo su `Id`me funciona la siguiente consulta:

```
-- suponiendo que consultamos para el albun Id=1
SELECT * FROM 
    Albunes AS a, 
    (
        SELECT COUNT(i.Id) AS Total FROM Imagenes AS i 
        WHERE i.Activo=1 AND fk_Id_Albunes= 1
    ) AS r
WHERE a.Activo=1
```

> Pero cuando intento generalizarla usando `a.Id` me da error la
>   siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT * FROM 
    Albunes AS a, 
    (
        SELECT COUNT(i.Id) AS Total FROM Imagenes AS i 
        WHERE i.Activo=1 AND fk_Id_Albunes= a.Id
    ) AS r
WHERE a.Activo=1
```

Que estoy haciendo mal o como hay que hacerlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

También se me ha ocurrido otra manera

```
SELECT a.*, COUNT(i.Id) FROM Albunes a INNER JOIN Imagenes i ON a.id = i.fk_Id_Albunes GROUP BY a.id;
```

Espero que esta sea la que necesitabas

Un saludo

Comment: Perfecto, si eso funciona, la estaba complicando nada mas. Muchas gracias.

Comment: De nada, hasta la próxima :)